# unable to get the difference between two numbers AND keep getting invalid amount when entering

Tags: java

```html
   This program will generate a random number and ask user to disperse
   the correct amount of change. If user has entered the wrong amount
   the program will say Incorrect by : +difference...
   mine refuses to work...
*/
// ---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7
// 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ChangeGame9
{
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int low = 1;
      int max = 10000;
      int twentyDollars = 0;
      int tenDollars = 0;
      int fiveDollars = 0;
      int oneDollar = 0;
      int quarters = 0;
      int dimes = 0;
      int nickels = 0;
      int pennies = 0;
      Random random = new Random();
      int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - low + 1);
      double randomNumber1 = (randomNumber /100.0); 
      double userAmount = twentyDollars * 20 + tenDollars * 10 +
                 fiveDollars * 5 + oneDollar * 1 + quarters * 0.25 
                 + dimes * 0.10 + nickels * 0.05 + pennies * 0.01;
      double difference = Math.abs( randomNumber1 - userAmount);
      
      double differenceOne = (int)(difference*100 + 0.5) / 100.0;

      
      
      
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      do  
      {
         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Twenties: "); 
         twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( twentyDollars <= 0 );
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Twenties: " );
            twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Tens: "); 
         tenDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( tenDollars < 0 || tenDollars > 1 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Tens: " );
            tenDollars = keyboard.nextInt(); 
         }

         
         System.out.println("Fives: "); 
         fiveDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( fiveDollars < 0 || fiveDollars > 1 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Fives: " );
            fiveDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         
         System.out.println("Ones: "); 
         oneDollar = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( oneDollar > 4 || oneDollar < 0 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Ones: " );
            oneDollar = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         
         System.out.println("Quarters: "); 
         quarters = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( quarters < 0 || quarters > 3 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Quarters: " );
            quarters = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         
         System.out.println("Dimes: "); 
         dimes = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( dimes < 0 || dimes > 2 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Dimes: " );
            dimes = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         
         System.out.println("Nickels: "); 
         nickels = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( nickels < 0 || nickels > 1 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Nickels: " );
            nickels = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         
         System.out.println("Pennies: "); 
         pennies = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( pennies < 0 || pennies > 4 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Pennies: " );
            pennies = keyboard.nextInt();
         }
         while ( differenceOne == 0)
         {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
         }
      }
         
      while( differenceOne != 0);
         {
            System.out.println("Incorrect by: " + differenceOne);
         }
   } 
}
```

----jGRASP exec: java ChangeGame9

Enter the change for 52.38
Twenties: 
2
** Invalid Amount **
Twenties: 
2
Tens: 
1
Fives: 
0
Ones: 
2
Quarters: 
1
Dimes: 
1
Nickels: 
0
Pennies: 
3
Enter the change for 52.38
Twenties: 
this is what is happening when I run my code...I don't understand what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while( twentyDollars <= 0 );
{
   System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
      "Twenties: " );
   twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

You have a semicolon after your while loop. This is interpreted as the body of your while loop being an empty statement, followed by the code that says invalid input.

If you notice, you can enter actual invalid input the second time it asks and it will accept it and continue onto the tens. Likewise if you enter invalid input at the first opportunity your program will freeze as it enters an infinite loop.

Comment: oh man! thanks! I had copied parts of my old code with that error and pasted with code that didn't...lol appreciate that. but now, I cant get it to give the difference at the end, it just asks for me to enter the correct change.

Comment: @L-G You'll probably want your code that calculates userInput, difference, and differenceOne to come after the user has inputted those values.